# Union and Intersection of $A_n$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

$A_n=\left(-\frac1n,n\right)$

I want to find $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.

So I try it then $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n=(-1,\infty)$ and $\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n=(0,1)$.

Can someone check my answer plz .

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX!  It's almost  correct: the intersection should be closed on the $0$ side.

Comment: As Bernard said $\bigcap A_n = [0,1)$. Prove your answers by showing they are equal as sets.